# Bring more users to meta.<sitename>

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, per-site-meta

If you've been to [any of the new Stack Exchange sites](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/), you've seen that each new site has its own meta. And at the top of each site, you'll see a byline to invite people into meta:

> <sub>got a question about the site itself? [meta.gadgets](http://meta.gadgets.stackexchange.com/) is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.</sub>

I would like to **generate more interest in the community-building discussions** during  the beta — to encourage more involvement in issues like [this stuff](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

I am looking for suggestions for a new byline. Something that is a bit more punchy and inviting. Something that says *"help build this site!"* and *"get involved!"* rather than just "if you have a question..."

Right now, meta looks like a place to go with problems. The goal is to portray meta as a larger concern to **everyone** on the site. I want people to understand that **the very *existence* and *health* of the site depends on their participation**.

If you have a suggestion for a new byline, submit it below (one suggestion per answer, so we can vote). If something is markedly better, maybe we can try it out.

Bonus points if it has marketing flair.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You might want to pick several and test out conversion rates.

Comment: I always tell them: if you have a beef with me, take it to meta!

Comment: @Ivo - I believe "Where's The Beef??" is still copyrighted by Wendy's.

Comment: @Robert - Thanks for raising this.

Comment: I think there may be some extra incentive if reputation earned in meta was counted towards the parent site's rep.

Comment: Yes. Credit to @Tim Post for the idea of improving the meta invite: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/162/bringing-more-users-to-meta.

Comment: @Tim, as long as we're ripping off of fast food, "Have it your way!" might be more apropos. Or... on second thought, "Delightfully tacky, yet unrefined."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We now highlight child metas in the sidebar as a house ad:

> [image: Visit Meta]

The rules for populating this question list are, to take the **hottest** ...

- questions tagged [featured]
- weekly
- front page hot

... from the child meta, in that order exactly, filling to 5 total. We also randomize the selection a bit so the list isn't so stale for regular visitors.

Answer (score 4):

> Get Involved! Speak Your Voice and Give Feedback at Meta.YourSiteNameHere.com!

Comment: Classic, but nice.

Answer (score 3):

> Go to meta. and suggest a better message.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you want REAL ULTIMATE POWER? Then come to meta.blagowhat.com and become part of our elite squad of ninjas shaping the destiny of this site!

<sub>(Okay, it probably wouldn't fly on the food SE, but I bet it would work on the techie sites.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> Want to know who is *really* controlling everything here? Visit meta.whatever.com - Schsssss: don't tell anyone!

Answer (score 1):

Stolen from today's most brilliant marketing geniuses:

> Ever sit and wonder what would happen if something great got even better? meta.*yoursitenamehere*

Comment: I am reminded of Snapple.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zoh0tHRXOvE

Comment: @Chacha102: wrong product. Think: *even more awesome* than Snapple...

Comment: Apple? (It is two characters shorter)

Comment: Hep C? Better than Hep B!

Comment: @Chacha102: *even shorter*

Comment: The letter 'E'?

Comment: @Chacha102: you disappoint me. It's the favorite food of pythonic vikings!

Comment: @Shog9: Spam, spam, spam, eggs, and spam!

Answer (score 1):

> I want people to understand that the very existence and health of the site depends on their participation.

---

WE'RE ALL GONNA DIEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE! (without you. meta.*yoursitenamehere*)

---

Answer (score 1):

> *Your* site - *Your* ideas - *Your* change - meta.guesswhat.com

Comment: Should actually be *our* changes, unless `status-declined`. But it would attract less people.

Comment: This is marketing, @Gnoupi. Go for damn lies!

Answer (score 1):

> [Site] does not end here. Go beyond and get involved in the decisions that help build this site and its community. Go to the back stage. Go to meta.[site].

Answer (score 1):

> Stack Overflow, Inc. Is now providing
>   funding to put great promotional ideas
>   into action that will help this community
>   grow [link to meta]

The individual sites should make an announcement prior, though explaining how the process works. That announcement should be written by all newly elected moderators / liaisons.

Answer (score 0):

> Having Problems with the site? Have an idea? Speak Your Voice at Meta.YourSiteNameHere.com

Comment: I'm not really looking to attract more people who have *problems*, per se. I'm trying to convey that the very *existence* and *health* of the site depends on their participation: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/. I clarified that in my original post.

Comment: @Robert I'm guessing the Unicorns and Waffles one doesn't fit your criteria then eh? :P

Comment: It's hard to tell sometimes, where unicorns are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

> Meta.YourSiteNameHere.com: Your place for [Site Topic], Unicorns, and Waffles.

Answer (score 0):

> [Site].com is ran by its users, like YOU. So get over to Meta.[Site].com and get involved!

Comment: I wont like being shoved around like this

Comment: Is ran? Is *run*.

Comment: 'Tis not your wont to like what you won't want, @Midhat.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Maybe I should *actually* try:

> The very *existence* and *health* of this site depends on your participation: meta.<sitename>

Comment: Well, it would definitely create a sense of urgency.

Comment: And it gives the idea that the site is in a desperate situation currently, hardly stable, ready to collapse. I mean, even if that was true, you don't want to say that.

Comment: @Gnoupi: True. Dialing it back a bit would be prudent.

Answer (score 0):

> Be a part and in control of what [site] is all about. Help shape your community. meta.[site]

Then grab the Sword of Omens and run headlong into the fray.

Comment: I miss my daily dose of Sword of Omens: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRsmoSis-2I#t=5m10s

Comment: @Robert - Snarf Snarf ...

Answer (score 0):

> Learn the secret to (insert one of) [weight loss|cure cancer|get rich|larger body parts]. Visit meta.sitenamehere.com now.

Answer (score 0):

> Your input shapes this community -
>   learn how to take a more active role
>   [here]

I suggest the link leading to the meta FAQ page, which would need a little more tweaking to roll out a slightly warmer welcome to people who want to get involved.

This is at the expense of assuming the people who go to meta are already somewhat familiar with how the site works, so perhaps the FAQ could be more on community building and less on how meta works.

Comment: Yes, cancer is [the emperor of all maladies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQ0Plh14h-U)

Answer (score 0):

Head over to meta if you want to have a say in how this site works (e.g., policy, moderator selection etc)